# Accuracy of time-domain filters and frequency domain filters

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, hilbert-transform

I am trying to calculate the Hilbert transform using 3 different method: `scipy.signal.hilbert` function, time domain filter, and frequency domain filter.

The test signal is $1/(1+t^{2})$, and its Hilbert transform is $t/(1+t^{2})$. In this result, the time domain filter is more accurate than scipy hilbert and frequency domain filter.

For the other test signal $\cos(2\pi ft)$, its Hilbert transform is $\sin(2\pi ft)$, where $f=127$Hz. When the signal is in $[0,1)$ second,  The frequency domain filter is more accurate than time domain filter. When the signal is in $[0,0.35)$ second,  The time domain filter is more accurate than frequency domain filter.

I am wondering what is the reason that the time domain filter or frequency domain filter are more accurate than the other one. Are there any requirements to use time domain filter or frequency domain filter?

Here's the code for the first test signal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal,fft

fs = 4096
time = np.arange(-10,10.,1./fs)
sig = 1/(1+time**2)

analytic_signal = signal.hilbert(sig)
amplitude_envelope = np.abs(analytic_signal)
instantaneous_phase = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal))
instantaneous_frequency = (np.diff(instantaneous_phase) / (2.0*np.pi) * fs)

order = 50001
co = [2*np.sin(np.pi*n/2)**2/np.pi/n for n in range(1, order+1)]
co1 = [2*np.sin(np.pi*n/2)**2/np.pi/n for n in range(-order, 0)]
co = co1+[0]+ co

out = signal.convolve(sig, co, mode='same', method='fft')

analytic_signal2 = sig + 1j*out
amplitude_envelope2 = np.abs(analytic_signal2)
instantaneous_phase2 = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal2))
instantaneous_frequency2 = (np.diff(instantaneous_phase2) / (2.0*np.pi) * fs)


sig_f = fft.fft(sig)
sig_f[0:int(len(sig_f)/2)] *= -1j
sig_f[int(len(sig_f)/2):len(sig_f)] *= 1j
new_sig = fft.ifft(sig_f)

analytic_signal3 = sig + 1j*new_sig
amplitude_envelope3 = np.abs(analytic_signal3)
instantaneous_phase3 = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal3))
instantaneous_frequency3 = (np.diff(instantaneous_phase3) / (2.0*np.pi) * fs)

plt.plot(time,np.imag(analytic_signal)-sig*time,linewidth=2,label='Scipy hilbert')
plt.plot(time,out-sig*time,label='Time domain')
plt.plot(time,new_sig-sig*time,label='Freq domain')
plt.title(r'$1/(1+t^{2})$')
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Error')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: The frequency domain method is overlapped with Scipy hilbert method]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to **edit your question**.  You do not define what you mean by "time domain filter" and "frequency domain filter".  **All** filters, digital or analog, that are applied to real signals in the real world are applied in the time domain.  We can tell ourselves differently, but at best we will be in error.  Since there are an infinite number of "time domain filters" and you used just one -- specify it, *in math*, not just code.  Since there are an infinite number of possible "frequency domain filters" *and* since the name is questionable -- specify it, *in math*.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve a continuous problem using a discrete math.

Everything you do numerically in a computer is discrete in both domains, which means it's also periodic in both domains.

> The test signal is $1/(1+t^2)$

No, it's not. Not if you represent it in a computer as a list of numbers. $1/(1+t^2)$ is not bandlimited, that means you can't sample it without aliasing. Furthermore, by doing an FFT you also sample the spectrum which means you have an infinite periodic repetition in the time domain as well.

Doing a Hilbert Transform numerically is tricky. A Hilbert Transformer is infinite it both time and frequency and it's also non-causal. Any type of numerical implementation can only be an approximation and the best way to approximate it depends on the requirements of your specific application. What do you care most about: time domain waveform, flatness in the pass-band, overall bandwidth, phase accuracy in the pass-band, etc.

Recommended read about the math of the discrete Hilbert transform: http://andrewduncan.net/air/